# Why does it seem like eslint and prettier are fighting one another?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli, prettier

I have eslint and prettier extensions installed on VSCode.  I usually use prettier to fix up and format my HTML.  I scaffolded a `vue-cli` project which installed several dev-dependancies for eslint and prettier:

```
"devDependencies": {,
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.13",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.14.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
  }
```

As I worked on this project, I had rules that I wanted to turn off; mainly eslint `no-unexpected-multiline`, prettier `printWidth` and some others I've noticed as I work.  But anytime I try to add these to either `.prettierrc.js` or `.eslintrc.js` (the prettier config file I had to manually create) it seems to just ignore them for the most part. I have no idea why.  It also ignores any comments I make for ignoring next lines and entire files (which I don't use often but is related), such as `// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier`.

Here's what my .eslintrc.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended", "@vue/prettier"],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint",
  },
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": "warn",
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-unexpected-multiline": "error",
  },
};
```

The only thing it seems to listen to under rules is `prettier/prettier` because I can turn if off.  I've had to turn it off to get rid of the lines all over my project because it wants to add each element property on new lines.

Here's the `prettierrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  tabWidth: 2,
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: false,
  printWidth: 200,
};
```

I've also had to turn off `formatOnSave`.   I'm pretty sure the issue lies in the `extends:` array but I don't know why.  All documentation for eslint I've read shows only a single plugin and not multiple like this has.

How can I get rules to work?

Comment: Yeah they don't play very well together. I remember spending ages matching the rules up. Why don't you just have eslint do your formatting?

Comment: Good idea.  Would I just remove `plugin:vue/essential` and `@vue/prettier` from the `extends` array?

Comment: Yes and from your package json. You also want to disable the prettier plugin in your vs code and install the eslint and set it as the default formatter.

Comment: Ok I will try that.  I swear I've spent more time fighting linters than actually coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had luck with the below -

.eslintrc.js

```
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended", "prettier"],
  plugins: ["prettier"],
```

In another project I am using this -

.eslintrc.js

```
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  ],
  plugins: ["prettier"],
```

prettierrc.js

```
// prettier.config.js or .prettierrc.js
module.exports = {
  endOfLine: "auto",
};
```

Comment: Well that is progress.  It only seems to show errors in the terminal for the last file I saved and when I run `npm run serve`.  I expected it to show in the problems tab of vscode.  But it is respecting the rules I create in prettierc.js.

Comment: Well I spoke too soon...  I can't figure out what is going on and where to put rules.  One minute it complains about changing to single quotes, then it doesn't.  I've added a rule `singleQuote: true,` to prettierrc.js and it doesn't complain, I've tried adding rules to eslintrc like this: `"prettier": {error: { semi: "true", singleQuote: "true" }},`.  It was complaining at first, now its not, I didn't change anything.

Comment: To start with, remove all your rules from prettierrc and remove the prettier rule from eslintrc.

inside your .code-workspace  add this:
 "settings": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
 }

Comment: Additionally, make sure the plugin has been added in eslintrc
plugins: ["prettier"],

Comment: Ok those are done.  This is so odd.  It seems to respect some rules, but not others. Here's what eslintrc looks like: https://i.imgur.com/xAmPkFs.png   ... One minute it respects the "lines-around-comments" rule, and they show up in problems tab, then suddenly it doesn't.  When I try to `npm run serve` it still shows all these:  https://i.imgur.com/uJUgauW.png  ...I know this is due to my lack of knowledge on all this but it's getting frustrating.

Comment: can you try replacing the 'semi' rule with this: 
semi: ["warn", "always"],

Comment: I actually figured it out not long after my last comment. it was a syntax issue, which your suggestion would have worked.  It is so confusing... I don't know where to add rules and when to use which rule...  I think I've almost got it though.  These rules are working well for me:  https://imgur.com/a/6KwZQl8  I had to turn prettier/prettier off because I wasn't sure where to put the rules for it, and it would flag everything in every file.

Comment: To expand on my last comment:   I also don't understand why some errors show up in the Problems tab in VSCODE, and some don't, but show up when I try to build the project.  For example I could have 2 files open, both with the same lint errors, but only one file will show up in the problems tab, the other only shows up when I try to build project... Though if I turn `prettier/prettier` to "error" in my eslintrc, the Problems tab fills with errors in all the files in my project... why does this have to be so inconsistent??

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/AhEneeS.png   Both files have very similar statements but only one is being flagged and showing up in the Problems tab.  The other is only caught after I try to build.

Comment: I feel your pain, it's very frustrating.  It takes a while to get used to, but after a while, it gets easier.
I'd take a look at the docs for this-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prettier

Comment: I appreciate your time and help.  Your answer above did help considerably though and counts as acceptable.  Much appreciated!